# After adding public key to gitlab still cli want login and password

Tags: git, authentication, gitlab, ssh-keys, key-pair

I need access to repository in gitlab. I am using windows 10. If i type in command line for ex. `git pull` i need enter login and password. So today i was trying set ssh keys. Directory in path %myProfile%/.ssh was no exist so i was used command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@domain.com"` (i am using gitbash) and now i have .ssh directory and keypair in it. So i was open `id_rsa.pub` (ctrl+a, ctrl+c) and added key to ssh keys via browser to my gitlab profile.

But problem is - command line still wants email and password. Why? Where i can set some autentification type or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the remote URL of your origin:

`git remote set-url origin <your ssh url>`

Or just clone it again with the SSH URL shown on the GitLab project page.